# Typescript Definition Files In Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

In an Ionic 2 project where is the best place to put custom typescript definition files? I would like to define some of the cordova plugin interfaces so VS Code will not see references to them as errors.

Comment: It's common to put `typings` folder next to or inside `src`, at the same level of `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Ah OK - In the current Ionic 2 directory structure the tsconfig.json is at the root. So I guess adding a folder called "typings" at the root is the way to go.

Comment: Actually the folder name does not matter, as long as the files inside are considered part of your TypeScript project. See `tsconfig.json` in TypeScript wiki for more information.

Comment: @vilicvane that looks like the answer, please consider making an actual answer out of it. :)

Comment: @toskv Thanks for reminding me. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common TypeScript project structure could be like:

```
- out
- src
  - script.ts
- typings
  - node
    - node.d.ts
  - global.d.ts
- tsconfig.json
```

Or with `tsconfig.json` file and `typings` (the name doesn't matter) folder put into `src`.

With a correct file structure, the key to this question becomes ensuring related files being recognized as part of the TypeScript project. You may refer to fields `files` and `exclude` of [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) for more information.

Compiler option `--listFiles` could also help to ensure your source files are properly included.